# SQLAlchemy delete cascade fails

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, innodb

I am having trouble deleting a model instance from within SQLAlchemy. I recently added an additional table and this addition has introduced this problem. The table I added is called `editrecords`.

The database is MySQL with an InnoDB engine.

Models are defined below:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Model = declarative_base(name='Model')

class HasId(object):
    @declared_attr
    def id(cls):
        return Column('id', Integer, Sequence('test_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    ...

class TestParent(HasId, Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tests'
    discriminator = Column(String(50))
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': discriminator}
    ...

class FooTest(TestParent):
    __tablename__ = 'footests'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'footests'}
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('tests.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), primary_key=True)
    ...

class EditRecord(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'editrecords'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('editrecord_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    test_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('tests.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False)
    ...
```

Here is the function where the delete occurs

```
def delete_test(test_id):
    test = TestParent.query.get(test_id)
    db_session.delete(test)
    db_session.commit()
    return( jsonify( {'deleted_test': test_id} ) )
```

I have tried modifying the `ForeignKey` property `ondelete='CASCADE'` on the models and rebuilding the database, although nothing is seeming to work. The `editrecords` table is giving me issues when I try to delete a test because it has a `ForeignKey` pointing to `tests`.

The error message I am getting is below (fired when I try to commit the transaction in `delete_test`)

```
IntegrityError: (pymysql.err.IntegrityError) (1452, u'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bayswater_DEV`.`editrecords`, CONSTRAINT `editrecords_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`test_id`) REFERENCES `tests` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)') [SQL: u'UPDATE editrecords SET test_id=%s WHERE editrecords.id = %s'] [parameters: (None, 2)]
```

EDIT: result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table>` for the above tables

tests: http://pastebin.com/uFcEMzVZ

footests: http://pastebin.com/62uhECYn

editrecords: http://pastebin.com/3LekPywN

Comment: can you login to mysql server and execute show create tables for above tables and get the result

Comment: it will help to identify the issue

Comment: @MaheshMadushanka I edited the question to include that information

Comment: A database-enforced cascading delete with the INNODB engine [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32298405). This means the db engine does the cascading delete for you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you have two foreign keys from foo tests and editrecord tables to test table

footests

```
CONSTRAINT `footests_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `tests` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `footests_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `footests` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

edotrecords

```
CONSTRAINT `editrecords_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`test_id`) REFERENCES `tests` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `editrecords_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`);
```

In this situation you cant have On delete cascade 
because lets assume if you delete record from **editrecord** then 
it will try to delete related record from test table (on Delete cascade)
but those test ids are using as foreign keys in **footest** table as well
due to that foregin key constrain it will not alow to delete those records from test table so your delete statement will fail

same thing happen if you going to delete it from foo test it has on delete cascade foreign key and it will try to delete records from test but they are already using as foreign keys in editrecord so it will not alowe to delete

this will be a dead look situation where you cant delete record from both table at same time. so please the issue is ON delete cascade and remove it from table level and handle it from code level

with this table design you cant delte entry from either footest or editrecord tables