# Entity Framework 5: Cascade Delete One to Many

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-5

I want to know how I can delete all my bankCheck when i want to delete my Customer.

This is my database

[image]

I made something like this:

```
ConEntities context = new ConEntities();
context.Customer.Attach(selectedCustomer);
context.Customer.Remove(selectedCustomer);
context.SaveChanges();
context.Dispose();
```

But i have this error:

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (``.`BankCheck`, CONSTRAINT `fk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idCustomer`)
>   REFERENCES `Customer` (`id`))"

**I put Cascade on my OnDelete End1**

Comment: What makes you conclude that the exception is related to cascaded delete? It isn't. Look at where `selectedCustomer` comes from.

Comment: In my selectedCustomer i have all my BankCheck. It come from my datagrid. And my exception related is when my context try to attach my selectedCustomer.

Comment: You should ask yourself  why it is still attached to the previous context.

Comment: Ok i have edited my post. I have an other error now.

Comment: A database-enforced cascading delete with the INNODB engine [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32298405). This means the db engine does the cascading delete for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16654828/how-to-remove-child-one-to-many-related-records-in-ef-code-first-database):

```
using (var context = new ConEntities())
{
    var parent = context.Customer.Include(p => p.Check).SingleOrDefault(s => s.id == selectedCustomer.id);

    if (parent.Check != null && parent.Check.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var child in parent.Check.ToList())
        {
            context.Check.Remove(child);
        }
    }

    context.Customer.Attach(parent);
    context.Customer.Remove(parent);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```