# Deleting from one table where a field on a foreign key is less than value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, foreign-keys, sql-delete

I have a database table called 'order' which references another table named 'delivery' through a foreign key. I need to delete deliveries modified before a certain date but I can't do so until I delete the orders that reference them.

So I need to delete orders where deliveries were modified before a certain date. I wrote the following query in MySQL:

```
DELETE FROM `order`,`delivery` WHERE order.delivery_id = delivery.id AND delivery.modifiedOn < '2016-2-28 23:59:59'
```

But I'm getting a SQL error:

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near: 'WHERE order.delivery_id = delivery.id AND delivery.modifiedOn < '2016-'

I've not done this kind of query before, I suspect I need to use a JOIN somewhere but not sure where - any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete from multiple tables in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331992/how-to-delete-from-multiple-tables-in-mysql)

Comment: So, just accept the duplicate callout at the top of your question if you want (for a multiple table delete if that is your situation, and I am not sure it is)

Comment: Jamie, the following is a simple example of cascading deletes [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32298405) ... about half way down the answer is an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the syntax you are looking for:

```
DELETE o, d
    FROM `order` o JOIN
         `delivery` d
         ON o.delivery_id = d.id 
    WHERE d.modifiedOn < '2016-02-29';
```

Notes:

- Don't name a table `order`.  It is a reserved word in MySQL and a keyword in SQL.  How about `Orders`?
- Learn to use proper `JOIN` syntax, even in non-`SELECT` queries.
- Table aliases make a query easier to write and to read.
- There is no need to include the HH:MM:SS for the time comparison.
- Do you realize that February 2016 actually had 29 days?
- Finally, cascading delete foreign key references would simplify the processing.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, can you explain what you mean by cascading delete foreign keys?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html . . . The specific syntax is `on delete cascade`.