# How can I use foreign key for two tables to record expenses?

Tags: mysql

I want to use two tables, "employee_expenses" and "expense_master" to record and output all employee expenses. How can I do this using foreign keys?

employee_expense columns: Employee_ID(PK)

expense_master columns: Employee(FK to Employee_ID), expense_ID(PK) date, description, expense amount

There are four possible inputs for description column which are chosen from dropdown menu (accommodation, food, travel, other). Hence, the expense_ID(PK) in expense_master table will only have four values - "1,2,3,4"

I want to be able to output like this, with a list of all expenses incurred by a particular employee, for every employee to view from his account:

[image]

The input UI looks like this: 
[image]

Please tell me what to do from here, i.e. what database action should be taken from here with regards to the two tables above, to make this happen, thanks.

Comment: Your question is so vague it is really hard to figure out what you are trying to do. Do you have a table for ExpenseType? Then you just have a foreign key from your Expense table to the ExpenseType table and keep the description in ExpenseType. Populate your dropdown from the ExpenseType table and your whole system will automatically pick up new types if you ever add one.

Comment: You should also be careful when tagging. mysql <> sql server

Comment: @SeanLange Sorry about the tagging. In the input UI, an employee can submit as many expenses as they want (press submit as many times for many expenses), however one table is not enough to do this as employee_id is a primary key, one table can only hold one expense per employee. However, I want an employee to be able to enter as many expenses as they want, so I'm trying to use foreign key to achieve this using two tables, but I'm unsure of how to do this.

Comment: How about if you share the table(s) you have now? The brief description you posted is not very clear what your current structure is like.

Comment: @SeanLange My current table is just a single table with columns employee_id(PK), date, description, expense incurred. However, with this, an employee can only enter one expense as their employee_id is a primary key. Hence why I want to use foreign key to achieve this, but unsure how to.

Comment: Why id the employee_id the primary key in an expense table? This would be a good time to use AUTO_INCREMENT as the primary key and employee_id as a foreign key to the employee table..

Comment: @SeanLange Can you please explain to me in an answer perhaps.

Comment: What part of it do you not understand? An expense table should NOT have the employee_id as the primary unless an employee can only ever have a single expense. That is why I suggested you should use AUTO_INCREMENT like ExpenseID or something.

Comment: @SeanLange Could you please explain exactly what the two tables are, each of their columns and properties (PK, FK)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117625/discussion-between-sean-lange-and-javaprogrammer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have asked very nicely repeatedly (including in chat with Sean). So I will share this. Sometimes we just need to accept that the guy doesn't know how to do it, and that any pointers to help are not working or understood. So ask away on the below.

```
drop table if exists employees;
create table employees
(   empId int auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(100) not null
);

drop table if exists expenses;
create table expenses
(   expId int auto_increment primary key,
    category varchar(50) not null, -- maybe this goes to its own FK
    amount decimal(12,2) not null,
    empId int not null,
    dtOccurred datetime not null, -- or just a `Date` datatype
    constraint `fk_exp_emp001` foreign key (empId) references employees(empId),
    key `key_exps_empid` (empId) -- maybe even a composite index: key(empId,dtOccurred)
);
```

**Test:**

```
insert expenses(category,amount,empId,dtOccurred) values ('fishing supplies',100,10,'2009-01-30');
-- above line, Error 1452: FK violation. Emp 10 does not exist

insert employees(name) values ('Jim Smith'); -- id 1
select last_insert_id(); -- returns 1
insert expenses(category,amount,empId,dtOccurred) values ('fishing supplies',100,1,'2009-01-30');
-- above inserts fine
```

Please see the last half of [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32298405) for Cascading Deletes. The MySQL Manual page, too, entitled [Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: Thanks very much :)

Comment: np. Just ping me if you get stuck.

Comment: I was not implying that Sean should have answered it. Only that you were simply in need and nice about it.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Thanks very much, and sorry Sean for pestering!

Comment: Thanks Drew!! I didn't post an answer because I would only have mangled the syntax. This was originally tagged with sql-server and mysql. I don't have mysql installed and have never actually used it so I would have struggled to get the syntax correct.