# Delete 2 id assoc from 2 different table

Tags: php, mysql

I need to remove associated id from **2 different tables**. For example, when I delete the `id 1` of `PulseTables` I want all the `id_table 1` of `PulseTasks` to be **automatically deleted**. Is this possible and how?

[image: Table 1]

[image: Table 2]

Comment: It is called `DELETE CASCADE` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511361/how-do-i-use-on-delete-cascade-in-mysql

Comment: Umm .. Try this! **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953624/how-to-delete-records-not-in**

Comment: do you want it by mysql query ? then normally use 2 query or you need to set FOREIGN key

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp