# delete functionality incremental load in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to delete records that are present in the destination table but not in the source table. The primary key in the destination table is an auto_increment ID which is not there in the source table. Both the source and destination tables contain a set of unique key combinations which can be used to uniquely identify the rows in either tables. What is the approach that I should follow? How can I delete if  I am to use multiple column combinations as the unique key and not one primary key(not there in source)?

```
 delete from dest_table
 where (uniq_key_col1,uniq_key_col2) not in (
   select dest.uniq_key_col1,dest.uniq_key_col2 
   from dest_table dest
   join source_table source
   on dest.uniq_key_col1=source.uniq_key_col1
   and dest.uniq_key_col2=source.uniq_key_col2
 )
```

This is how it should ideally look (provided just for clarity and please ignore the error in where clause because of multiple columns)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Delete Records NOT IN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953624/how-to-delete-records-not-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like NOT [EXISTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is what you need

```
DELETE d FROM dest_table d 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT (PUT_APPROPRIATE_COLUMNS_HERE) from source_table s 
   WHERE d.col1 = s.col
   AND d.col2 = s.col2
   ... etc for other columns
   )
```

Note the table aliasing, you need that. And it might be more appropriate to use an inner join, if that is possible with your data.

Comment: as in, list the columns you want in the SELECT, or * if preferred

Comment: What would it matter if you have a list of columns or * or any literal like 1 or 'x' in a select that is used for EXISTS query?

Comment: could do - the asker seemed to want a list of columns so I indicated where to list them if wanted.  '1' is also an 'appropriate' column

Comment: EXISTS query doesn't deal with the list of columns and no matter what returns a simple boolean value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use exists. ie:

```
delete from dest_table
 where not exists (
   select * 
   from source_table source
   where dest_table.uniq_key_col1=source.uniq_key_col1
   and dest_table.uniq_key_col2=source.uniq_key_col2
 );
```

Comment: This appears to be the first answer using `not exists`, so it deservers to be upvoted.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I agree - Even though i was only 5 seconds behind :P

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this :

```
DELETE
FROM dbo.dest a 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
        FROM dbo.source1 b
       WHERE a.id1 = b.ID1 and a.id2 = b.id2
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option for you

```
DELETE dest_table
FROM dest_table
    LEFT JOIN source_table
        ON dest_table.uniq_key_col1 = source_table.uniq_key_col1
            AND dest_table.uniq_key_col2 = source_table.uniq_key_col2
WHERE source_table.uniq_key_col1 IS NULL
```