# SQL - find records from one table which exist in another and delete if not

Tags: sql, union-all

I've got the following four SQL tables:

```
Table 1:
-----------------------
Product | Date_Purchase
-----------------------
abc     | 06-Jan-19
def     | 05-Jan-18
ghi     | 05-Apr-19
abc     | 06-Feb-19

Table 2:

------------------------
Product | Date_Purchase
------------------------
jkl    | 6-Feb-19
mno    | 2-Aug-18
ghi    | 9-May-19
pqr    | 1-Sep-19

Table 3:

-------------------------
Product | Date_Purchase
-------------------------
ghi    | 2-Aug-18
mno    | 9-May-19
pqr    | 2-Aug-18
abc    | 06-Jan-19

Table 4:

-------------------------
Product | Date_Purchase
-------------------------
stu    | 9-May-19
vwx    | 05-Apr-19
ghi    | 9-May-19
def    | 05-Jan-18
```

I've got the below code which joins the tables with Union:

```
SELECT Product, Date_Purchase FROM Table1 UNION ALL
SELECT Product, Date_Purchase FROM Table2 UNION ALL
SELECT Product, Date_Purchase FROM Table3 UNION ALL SELECT Product, Date_Purchase FROM Table4
ORDER BY Product, Date_Purchase;
```

I would like to delete all the rows from the tables, no matter the table, that appear only once in all the tables.

For example jkl, stu and vwx appear only once, so I would like to delete the entire rows from the table where they appear. Does anyone have any idea how to do that?
Also how could i delete all the products that appear in the tables and have the same purchase date?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Delete Records NOT IN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953624/how-to-delete-records-not-in)

Comment: What DBMS are you using (Oracle, MySQL, etc.)? I doubt you'll be able to delete from all four tables in one operation. You'll probably need to populate all items to delete into a temporary table, then perform four deletes (one for each source table) to delete any items found in the temporary table.

Comment: Did you manage to solve your issue? Then please let us know.

Comment: The solution provided by forpas worked! thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution for MySql with which in 1 statement you can delete from all 4 tables:

```
delete t1, t2, t3, t4
from (
  select u.product, count(*) counter 
  from (
    select * from table1 union all
    select * from table2 union all
    select * from table3 union all
    select * from table4
  ) u  
  group by u.product
) t 
left join table1 t1 on t1.product = t.product
left join table2 t2 on t2.product = t.product
left join table3 t3 on t3.product = t.product
left join table4 t4 on t4.product = t.product
where t.counter = 1;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=865d7b2a5771abeb31ae1a5f65e8880c).
Results:
Table1

```
> Product | Date_Purchase
> :------ | :------------
> abc     | 06-Jan-19    
> def     | 05-Jan-18    
> ghi     | 05-Apr-19    
> abc     | 06-Feb-19
```

Table2

```
> Product | Date_Purchase
> :------ | :------------
> mno     | 2-Aug-18     
> ghi     | 9-May-19     
> pqr     | 1-Sep-19
```

Table3

```
> Product | Date_Purchase
> :------ | :------------
> ghi     | 2-Aug-18     
> mno     | 9-May-19     
> pqr     | 2-Aug-18     
> abc     | 06-Jan-19
```

Table4

```
> Product | Date_Purchase
> :------ | :------------
> ghi     | 9-May-19     
> def     | 05-Jan-18
```

Answer (score 0):

If "delete" means not returning return them in a `select`, then:

```
SELECT pd.*
FROM (SELECT pd.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Product) as cnt
      FROM ((SELECT Product, Date_Purchase FROM Table1
            ) UNION ALL
            (SELECT Product, Date_Purchase FROM Table2
            ) UNION ALL
            (SELECT Product, Date_Purchase FROM Table3
            ) UNION ALL
            (SELECT Product, Date_Purchase FROM Table4
            )
           ) pd
     ) pd
WHERE cnt = 1;
```

If "delete" means, `delete`, then you need four `delete` statements, each like this:

```
delete t
   from table1 t
   where not exists (select 1 from table2 where t2.product = t.product) and
         not exists (select 1 from table3 where t3.product = t.product) and
         not exists (select 1 from table4 where t4.product = t.product);
```

Actually, this delete products that are only in on table, even if they are there multiple times.  It can be tweaked to only delete the singletons, if that is also necessary.

Comment: What if "appear only once in all the tables" include the purchase date?

Comment: @Scratte For the first or the second version?

Comment: @Nikolaus Both. abc from abc | 06-Feb-19 (table1) will not appear on the first.

Comment: @Scratte . . . That would be a different question.  If you are interested, you can ask *that* question as a NEW question.

Answer (score 0):

To give it a try for Scratte‘s version of only if product and Date occurs twice (unchecked because written on mobile device):

```
SELECT pdo.*
FROM (SELECT pd.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Product) as cnt
      FROM ((SELECT Product, Date_Purchase FROM Table1
            ) UNION ALL
            (SELECT Product, Date_Purchase FROM Table2
            ) UNION ALL
            (SELECT Product, Date_Purchase FROM Table3
            ) UNION ALL
            (SELECT Product, Date_Purchase FROM Table4
            )
           ) pd
     ) pdo
Group by pdo.Product,pdo.Date_Purchase
Having cnt=1
```